# Find the set difference between two large arrays (matrices) in Python

Tags: python, numpy, set-difference

I have two large 2-d arrays and I'd like to find their set difference taking their rows as elements. In Matlab, the code for this would be `setdiff(A,B,'rows')`. The arrays are large enough that the obvious looping methods I could think of take too long.

Comment: What do you mean by "set difference"?

Comment: @user1443118 I'm guessing that he means "values in A that are not in B." as per http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/setdiff.html.

Comment: "set difference" as in "set difference" the set theory operation?

Comment: How does you 2-d array look like? a list of lists?

Comment: Are the arrays the same dimensions?

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for, but there is a 1D version (setdiff1d) [http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html]

Comment: The 2-d arrays are numpy array objects with the same number of columns but different numbers of rows.

Answer (score 19):

This **should** work, but is currently broken in 1.6.1 due to an unavailable mergesort for the view being created. It works in the pre-release 1.7.0 version. This should be the fastest way possible, since the views don't have to copy any memory:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> a2 = np.array([[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,1,1]])
>>> a1_rows = a1.view([('', a1.dtype)] * a1.shape[1])
>>> a2_rows = a2.view([('', a2.dtype)] * a2.shape[1])
>>> np.setdiff1d(a1_rows, a2_rows).view(a1.dtype).reshape(-1, a1.shape[1])
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

You can do this in Python, but it might be slow:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> a2 = np.array([[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,1,1]])
>>> a1_rows = set(map(tuple, a1))
>>> a2_rows = set(map(tuple, a2))
>>> a1_rows.difference(a2_rows)
set([(1, 2, 3)])
```

Comment: Thanks. The bottom method eventually crashed, but once I figure out how to install the new version of numpy I'll try the top method.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a nice alternative pure numpy solution that works for 1.6.1. It does create an intermediate array, so this may or may not be a problem for you. It also does not rely on any speedup from a sorted array or not (as `setdiff` probably does).

```
from numpy import *
# Create some sample arrays
A =random.randint(0,5,(10,3))
B =random.randint(0,5,(10,3))
```

As an example, this is what I got - note that there is one common element:

```
>>> A
array([[1, 0, 3],
       [0, 4, 2],
       [0, 3, 4],
       [4, 4, 2],
       [2, 0, 2],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 2],
       [4, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [2, 0, 2]])
>>> B
array([[4, 1, 3],
       [4, 3, 0],
       [0, 3, 3],
       [3, 0, 3],
       [3, 4, 0],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [4, 1, 2],
       [0, 4, 2],
       [0, 0, 3]])
```

We look for when the (L1) distance between the rows is zero. This gives us a matrix, which at the points where it is zero, these are the items common to both lists:

```
idx = where(abs((A[:,newaxis,:] - B)).sum(axis=2)==0)
```

As a check:

```
>>> A[idx[0]]
array([[0, 4, 2]])
>>> B[idx[1]]
array([[0, 4, 2]])
```

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? I'm welcome to any criticism or comments on how to improve.

Comment: Thanks for the clever code (I'll remember the newaxis formulation).  Unfortunately, when I tried it I got the error: "ValueError: array is too big."

Comment: @user1590405  When you run `A.size()` and `B.size()` how big are the arrays?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are going for, but this will get you a boolean array of where 2 arrays are not equal, and will be numpy fast:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(5, 5)
b = np.random.randn(5, 5)
a[0,0] = 10.0
b[0,0] = 10.0 
a[1,1] = 5.0
b[1,1] = 5.0
c = ~(a-b==0)
print c
```

[[False  True  True  True  True]
 [ True False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]]

Comment: This is not correct, it compares the elements. OP is looking for the set diff of the **rows**.

Comment: It's true that "`a[0, c[0]]` gives the elements in the 0 row of a not in b", but the way I read the question was not to find the elements of A and B per row that were identical, but to find the _rows_ of A and the _rows_ of B that matched.

Comment: From the match matrix however you can easily go to an array giving the row match using `np.all(match_matrix, axis=0)` however.