# Matrix row difference, output a boolean vector

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, set-difference

I have an `m x 3` matrix `A` and its row subset `B` (`n x 3`). Both are sets of indices into another, large 4D matrix; their data type is `dtype('int64')`. I would like to generate a boolean vector `x`, where `x[i] = True` if `B` does not contain row `A[i,:]`.

There are no duplicate rows in either `A` or `B`.

I was wondering if there's an efficient way how to do this in Numpy? I found an answer that's somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11903368/265289; however, it returns the actual rows (not a boolean vector).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could follow the same pattern as shown in [jterrace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11903368/190597), except use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) instead of `np.setdiff1d`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2015)

m, n = 10, 5
A = np.random.randint(10, size=(m,3))
B = A[np.random.choice(m, n, replace=False)]
print(A)
# [[2 2 9]
#  [6 8 5]
#  [7 8 0]
#  [6 7 8]
#  [3 8 6]
#  [9 2 3]
#  [1 2 6]
#  [2 9 8]
#  [5 8 4]
#  [8 9 1]]

print(B)
# [[2 2 9]
#  [1 2 6]
#  [2 9 8]
#  [3 8 6]
#  [9 2 3]]

def using_view(A, B, assume_unique=False):
    Ad = np.ascontiguousarray(A).view([('', A.dtype)] * A.shape[1])
    Bd = np.ascontiguousarray(B).view([('', B.dtype)] * B.shape[1])
    return ~np.in1d(Ad, Bd, assume_unique=assume_unique)

print(using_view(A, B, assume_unique=True))
```

yields

```
[False  True  True  True False False False False  True  True]
```

You can use `assume_unique=True` (which can speed up the calculation) since
there are no duplicate rows in `A` or `B`.

---

Beware that `A.view(...)` will raise

```
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

if `A.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']`  is `False` (i.e. if `A` is not a C-contiguous array).
Therefore, in general we need to use `np.ascontiguous(A)` before calling `view`.

---

As B.M. suggests, you could instead view each row using the ["void"
dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html):

```
def using_void(A, B):
    dtype = 'V{}'.format(A.dtype.itemsize * A.shape[-1])
    Ad = np.ascontiguousarray(A).view(dtype)
    Bd = np.ascontiguousarray(B).view(dtype)
    return ~np.in1d(Ad, Bd, assume_unique=True)
```

This is safe to use with integer dtypes. However, note that

```
In [342]: np.array([-0.], dtype='float64').view('V8') == np.array([0.], dtype='float64').view('V8')
Out[342]: array([False], dtype=bool)
```

so using `np.in1d` after viewing as void may return incorrect results for arrays
with float dtype.

---

Here is a benchmark of some of the proposed methods:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2015)

m, n = 10000, 5000
# Note A may contain duplicate rows, 
# so don't use assume_unique=True for these benchmarks. 
# In this case, using assume_unique=False does not improve the speed much anyway.
A = np.random.randint(10, size=(2*m,3))
# make A not C_CONTIGUOUS; the view methods fail for non-contiguous arrays
A = A[::2]  
B = A[np.random.choice(m, n, replace=False)]

def using_view(A, B, assume_unique=False):
    Ad = np.ascontiguousarray(A).view([('', A.dtype)] * A.shape[1])
    Bd = np.ascontiguousarray(B).view([('', B.dtype)] * B.shape[1])
    return ~np.in1d(Ad, Bd, assume_unique=assume_unique)

from scipy.spatial import distance
def using_distance(A, B):
    return ~np.any(distance.cdist(A,B)==0,1)

from functools import reduce 
def using_loop(A, B):
    pred = lambda i: A[:, i:i+1] == B[:, i]
    return ~reduce(np.logical_and, map(pred, range(A.shape[1]))).any(axis=1)

from pandas.core.groupby import get_group_index, _int64_overflow_possible
from functools import partial
def using_pandas(A, B):
    shape = [1 + max(A[:, i].max(), B[:, i].max()) for i in range(A.shape[1])]
    assert not _int64_overflow_possible(shape)

    encode = partial(get_group_index, shape=shape, sort=False, xnull=False)
    a1, b1 = map(encode, (A.T, B.T))
    return ~np.in1d(a1, b1)

def using_void(A, B):
    dtype = 'V{}'.format(A.dtype.itemsize * A.shape[-1])
    Ad = np.ascontiguousarray(A).view(dtype)
    Bd = np.ascontiguousarray(B).view(dtype)
    return ~np.in1d(Ad, Bd)

# Sanity check: make sure all the functions return the same result
for func in (using_distance, using_loop, using_pandas, using_void):
    assert (func(A, B) == using_view(A, B)).all()
```

---

```
In [384]: %timeit using_pandas(A, B)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.99 ms per loop

In [381]: %timeit using_void(A, B)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.72 ms per loop

In [378]: %timeit using_view(A, B)
10 loops, best of 3: 35.6 ms per loop

In [383]: %timeit using_loop(A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 342 ms per loop

In [379]: %timeit using_distance(A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 502 ms per loop
```

Comment: Beautiful. you can win a two factor by juste writing  `Ad = A.view('V12')` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, @B.M.; I've added `using_void` to the mix.

Answer (score 3):

since there are only 3 columns, one solution would be to just *reduce* accross columns:

```
>>> a
array([[2, 2, 9],
       [6, 8, 5],
       [7, 8, 0],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [3, 8, 6],
       [9, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 6],
       [2, 9, 8],
       [5, 8, 4],
       [8, 9, 1]])
>>> b
array([[2, 2, 9],
       [1, 2, 6],
       [2, 9, 8],
       [3, 8, 6],
       [9, 2, 3]])

>>> from functools import reduce
>>> pred = lambda i: a[:, i:i+1] == b[:,i]
>>> reduce(np.logical_and, map(pred, range(a.shape[1]))).any(axis=1)
array([ True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

though this would create an `m x n` intermediate array which may not be memory efficient.

Alternatively, if the values are *indices*, i.e. non-negative integers, you may use [`pandas.groupby.get_group_index`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/383865f2d6481ae19e1ef3b19806fa99ac26b286/pandas/core/groupby.py#L3516) to reduce to one dimensional arrays. This is an efficient algorithm which pandas use internally for `groupby` operations; The only caveat is that you may need to verify that there will not be any integer overflow:

```
>>> from pandas.core.groupby import get_group_index, _int64_overflow_possible
>>> from functools import partial

>>> shape = [1 + max(a[:, i].max(), b[:, i].max()) for i in range(a.shape[1])]
>>> assert not _int64_overflow_possible(shape)

>>> encode = partial(get_group_index, shape=shape, sort=False, xnull=False)
>>> a1, b1 = map(encode, (a.T, b.T))
>>> np.in1d(a1, b1)
array([ True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat `A` and `B` as two sets of XYZ arrays and calculate the `euclidean distances` between them with [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html). The zero distances would be of interest to us. This distance calculation is supposed to be a pretty efficient implementation, so hopefully we would have an efficient solution to solve our case. So, the implementation to find such a boolean output would look like this -

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

out = ~np.any(distance.cdist(A,B)==0,1)
# OR np.all(distance.cdist(A,B)!=0,1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [582]: A
Out[582]: 
array([[0, 2, 2],
       [1, 0, 3],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [2, 0, 3],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])

In [583]: B
Out[583]: 
array([[2, 0, 3],
       [2, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 3]])

In [584]: out
Out[584]: array([False,  True,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```