# ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm running into the following exception when operating on a third-party-supplied numpy dataset:

```
ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array
```

Under what circumstances will numpy raise this? My code is applying a view on the numpy array, where I'm trying to apply a structured `dtype` that matches the number of elements in a row.

I'm seeing this error when the statement `X.view([('', X.dtype)] * X.shape[1])` is called inside a function `f` - but not in every call to this function `f`:

```
ipdb> X.view([('', X.dtype)] * X.shape[1])
*** ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array.
```

`X` is always an array with two axis (`len(X.shape)` is always 2), so you'd expect a structured `dtype` that is `X.shape[1]` long to fit the last axis (`X.shape[1]`).

The exception does not happen for all datasets, so what causes numpy to throw this for *some* arrays but not others? I can't even see which .py numpy source code is throwing this error.

I'm finding it hard to produce a MCVE for this, but I've narrowed this down to a [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t_xnVzCcvbYEFT9qEDoY8Z_4lvubk-8D) that is still a little large to post here.

Here `X` is supposed to be a subset of the `iris` dataset, which I got from scikit learn.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
X = load_iris().data
```

My code looks like this:

```
def f(X):
    X_rows = X.view([('', X.dtype)] * X.shape[1])

def g(X):
    f(X)

def h(X):
    f(X)

# call the functions
g(X) # this runs without a problem
f(X) # this returns the error
```

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of X?

Comment: @hpaulj It's the iris data set from scikitlearn as shown in the code. I don't have access to my computer but I believe they are `np. ndarray` and `[150,4] `.

Comment: @J.Doe: `ndarray` is the array type, not the `dtype` of the values.

Comment: looks like this code is trying to change a 2d array into a 1d structured array, replacing, for example, 4 column `int64` array with a 4 field structured array.  `np.unique` does this, though with a slightly different syntax (it names the fields)

Comment: @hpaulj I'm trying to get the set difference of two numpy arrays using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11903368/11159873) that used `np.setdiff1d`.

Comment: The question is, there some `dtype` and/or `shape` that reproduces this problem.  A more fundamental question, is the `dtype` simple, like `int64`, or is it already compound?

Comment: When that linked answer was written `np.unique` only worked with 1d arrays.  Since then it has added the axis parameter, but the underlying action is to first turn the array into a 1d one using this kind of structured dtype.

Comment: Loading as in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html, `dtype` is `float64`.  `X_rows` is (150,1) with `dtype([('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8')])`

Comment: @hpaulj I'm sorry for my comment about `X`. Actually it is a subset of the iris data set (`(6, 4)`, `('float64')` ). I couldn't think of narrowing down the problem; please run [this Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t_xnVzCcvbYEFT9qEDoY8Z_4lvubk-8D) to reproduce this issue

Comment: So the array isn't directly from the dataset, but rather is part of `pandas` dataframe `apply` operation?  I'm not going to try to guess what pandas has done with shape and dtype at this point.  [mcve]

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the welcoming experience to SO! In a parallel universe, this question would have been closed on the grounds of not providing an MCVE - which I still can't think how to produce. I think this thread would serve a lot better in future if an MCVE is provided, so please edit the question completely if you think a such formulation is possible. Also note that Google didn't have any search results on SO for this error too.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks a lot for the efforts and of course accepting this question though it is not really an SO-type of a question. As for the MCVE, please see my suggestion to Martijn above- feel free to edit the question completely.

Comment: @J.Doe: This is more of a 'under what conditions will numpy raise this exception* kind-of question, which for this specific case is a reasonably scoped question. That it has a basis in a hard-to-reduce real code case doesn't necessarily make it a debugging question. I'll edit the post to refocus it a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to create a view on an array with an incompatible memory layout, where the output `dtype` has an [itemsize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.itemsize.html) that doesn't cleanly fit the number of bytes needed in memory to cover the full length of the 'last' axis of the source array. The exception would also apply if you were just setting the `.dtype` attribute on the array *directly*, not just to `ndarray.view()` (which creates a new `ndarray` with `dtype` set on that new object).

The 'last' axis here is the 'innermost' dimension *in terms of the memory layout*; for C-order arrays that's `shape[-1]`, for Fortran-order arrays that's `shape[0]`. That dimension size times the original `dtype.itemsize` must be divisible by the new `dtype.itemsize`, or otherwise you can't 'walk' over the internal memory structure cleanly.

For example, for a C-order (row-major order) array with shape `(4, 3, 5)` and a `dtype.itemsize` of 8, the 'last' axis takes up 5 * 8 == 40 bytes of memory, and so you can create a view on this with larger dtypes of sizes 10, 20 and 40. The same array but in *Fortran* order (column-major order), however, uses 4 * 8 == 32 bytes of memory, limiting your options to larger dtypes of sizes 16 and 32 only.

If `X.view([('', X.dtype)] * X.shape[1])` fails, then either `X.shape` has more dimenions than just 2, *or* it is an array using Fortran-ordering. You can correct for the first by using `X.shape[-1]` and you can check for the lattr by looking at [`ndarray.flags['F_CONTIGUOUS']`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html#numpy.ndarray.flags). Combining these into one expression like the following should work:

```
X_rows = X.view([('', X.dtype)] * X.shape[0 if X.flags['F_CONTIGUOUS'] else -1])
```

*However*, as the [`ndarray.view()` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html#numpy.ndarray.view) warns:

> Views that change the `dtype` size (bytes per entry) should normally be avoided on arrays defined by slices, transposes, fortran-ordering, etc.[.]

When you try to change the dtype of a Fortran-order array, a warning is raised:

```
DeprecationWarning: Changing the shape of an F-contiguous array by descriptor assignment is deprecated. To maintain the Fortran contiguity of a multidimensional Fortran array, use 'a.T.view(...).T' instead
```

so it'd be better to transpose the array, create your view, then transpose the resulting view again:

```
if X.flags['F_CONTIGUOUS']:
    X_rows = X.T.view([('', X.dtype)] * X.shape[0]).T
```

You still need to stick to `X.shape[0]` here, that's `shape[-1]` of the transposed array.

The fact that support for changing the `dtype` on Fortran-order arrays is deprecated also can explain the exception's reference to the 'last axis', which is perfectly natural in terms of C-order arrays but feels counter-intuitive when applied to Fortran-order arrays.

> I can't even see which .py numpy source code is throwing this error.

Numpy is primarily written in C (with a dash of Fortran 77), and so you need to dig into the source code of the compiled components. The error is thrown in the [`dtype` descriptor setter function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/cf73967fae0a68344a0b246d6dcd898ec1e84343/numpy/core/src/multiarray/getset.c#L578-L590), which here is called when the [`PyArray_View()` function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b637e654706ae7efbf556091cb663197e2f28774/numpy/core/src/multiarray/convert.c#L597-L641) calls the `PyObject_SetAttrString()` function to set the `dtype` attribute when it is being called from the [`ndarray.view()` method](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8f37d88ebc0f265e451d7f5bca6d6ad885341a83/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L242-L287).

According to the source code, not only is changing the dtype of Fortran-order arrays  deprecated, but views on non-contiguous arrays are not supported at all (meaning that if both `X.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']` and `X.flags['F_CONTIGUOUS']` are `False` then you can't change the `dtype` at all).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Martijn Pieters. However, I can't think of relating this to my problem. If you `%debug` after running the [Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t_xnVzCcvbYEFT9qEDoY8Z_4lvubk-8D) I uploaded to reproduce this problem, you can see that `X` is of`float64` dtype and there's no dtype conversion,

Comment: @J.Doe: out of time now, but the shape of the array is also important, `.shape[0]` is 6, and 6 times 8 bytes doesn't fit into 32 bytes per item in the view.

Comment: IIUC, isn't `.shape[1]`(4) the length that should be of interest? Also, why can't I reproduce this with `a = np.array([[4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],[4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],[4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],[4.4, 3. , 1.3, 0.2],[4.4, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],[4.6, 3.2, 1.4, 0.2]], dtype='float64')
` and `a.view([('', a.dtype)] * a.shape[1])`?

Comment: I reproduced your error - by assigning `order='F'` to your `a`.

Comment: @J.Doe: back now, and I'm seeing it now. The array you are working with is a view, with a *strided view* across the array. I'll find the doc references and write up what's going on.

Comment: @J.Doe: I think I've got it fully covered now, and verified against your notebook. You have a Fortran-order contiguous array there, so it is indeed `shape[0]` that matters here, not `shape[-1]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartijnPieters This isn't something that a layman python programmer like me would solve!

Answer (score 1):

So trying to reproduce your situation:

```
In [129]: from sklearn import datasets                                          
In [131]: iris = datasets.load_iris()                                           

In [132]: X = iris.data                                                         
In [133]: X.shape                                                               
Out[133]: (150, 4)
In [134]: X.dtype                                                               
Out[134]: dtype('float64')

In [135]: X_rows = X.view([('',X.dtype)] * X.shape[1])                          
In [136]: X_rows.shape                                                          
Out[136]: (150, 1)
In [137]: X_rows.dtype                                                          
Out[137]: dtype([('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8')])
```

So far looks good.

---

I was about giveup, since I didn't want to debug your notebook.  But I may have hit on a possible cause.

At the start of your run there's a warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:14: DeprecationWarning: Changing the shape of an F-contiguous array by descriptor assignment is deprecated. To maintain the Fortran contiguity of a multidimensional Fortran array, use 'a.T.view(...).T' instead
```

You are running this function with a pandas `apply`, which I haven't used much.  But I am aware that pandas prefers an 'F' order, since it is Series oriented.  So what happens if I switch `X` to that order?

```
In [148]: X1 = X.copy(order='F')                                                
In [149]: X_rows = X1[:0].view([('',X1.dtype)] * X1.shape[1])                   
In [150]: X_rows                                                                
Out[150]: 
array([], shape=(0, 1),
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8')])
In [151]: X_rows = X1[:6].view([('',X1.dtype)] * X1.shape[1])                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-151-f3272035dc14> in <module>
----> 1 X_rows = X1[:6].view([('',X1.dtype)] * X1.shape[1])

ValueError: To change to a dtype of a different size, the array must be C-contiguous
```

OK, it's not the same error, but it does show that order can affect this type of `view`.

---

But let's take the array from your comment - and give it an order `F`:

```
In [153]: a = np.array([[4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],[4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],[4.6, 3.4, 1.4
     ...: , 0.3],[4.4, 3. , 1.3, 0.2],[4.4, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],[4.6, 3.2, 1.4, 0.2]]
     ...: , dtype='float64', order='F')                                         

In [154]: a.view([('', a.dtype)] * a.shape[1])                                  
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: Changing the shape of an F-contiguous array by descriptor assignment is deprecated. To maintain the Fortran contiguity of a multidimensional Fortran array, use 'a.T.view(...).T' instead
  #!/usr/bin/python3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-b804730eb70b> in <module>
----> 1 a.view([('', a.dtype)] * a.shape[1])

ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array.
```

This is it - the warning, and error as shown in notebook.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj this is an interesting find. Any reason you can think of as to why pandas is doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but just a comment to @martijn answer. For a large dataset, I was getting this error in a similar operation of converting to view. It seems like whenever numpy decides to create an F order array the error pos up. The dataset that I'm working with is quite uniform, not sure why numpy decides to sometimes create an F order and C order array other. Hopefully, someone can explain.
Anyways my fix was to convert from F order to C order.

```
    if arr2.flags['F_CONTIGUOUS']:  # ‘C_CONTIGUOUS’ (‘C’) - ensure a C-contiguous array
        arr2 = np.require(arr1, requirements= ["C"])
        logging.critical("Switching from Fortran to Cstyle ")
```

Answer (score -1):

Please follow this:

```
M=np.ascontiguousarray(X, dtype=np.int64) 
# **int64** is type of my array. 
# please be careful about the right type of your array!
m_rows = M.view([('', M.dtype)] * M.shape[1])
```

With this method I did not get the error anymore.