# Compare numpy arrays of different shapes, row wise, delete same values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, compare

Compare arrays of two different shapes for example:

```
a:
([[1,2],
[3,4],
[5,6],
[7,8],
[9,10]])

b:
([[3,4],
[5,6]])

c = a -b
```

expected output:

```
c:
([[1,2],
[7,8],
[9,10]])
```

So far what I've tried usually results in:
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (21,2) (5,2)

Comment: Basically it look slike you want to compare these as "sets", and thus calculate the set difference?

Comment: Basically yes, you can say that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the set difference between two large arrays (matrices) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903083/find-the-set-difference-between-two-large-arrays-matrices-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numpy has a [`setdiff1d` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html), the problem is it ravels the arrays (so they become 1d) and the result is also 1d.

with a tiny trick using `.view` we can make numpy think your arrays are already 1d, with tuple elements, and then use `setdiff1d` and reshape it afterwards.

try this:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4],
              [5, 6],
              [7, 8],
              [9, 10]])

b = np.array([[3, 4],
              [5, 6]])

a_rows = a.view([('', a.dtype)] * a.shape[1])
b_rows = b.view([('', b.dtype)] * b.shape[1])

c = np.setdiff1d(a_rows, b_rows).view(a.dtype).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1  2]
 [ 7  8]
 [ 9 10]]
```