# Remove the intersection of 2 arrays in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 array:

```
old_array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
new_array = [[10,11,12],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[13,14,15]]
```

is there an easy algoritm to remove the rows who are already in old_array from new_array, so that the value of new_array is eventually

```
new_array = [[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the set difference between two large arrays (matrices) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903083/find-the-set-difference-between-two-large-arrays-matrices-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[i for i in new_array if i not in old_array]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use set differences:

```
>>> np.array(list(set(map(tuple, new_array)).difference(set(map(tuple, old_array)))))
array([[13, 14, 15],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```